# What are likely root causes of "Failed to list data bag items in data bag"?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I keep getting this error from Chef but can't find any documentation or other people who have had it.

What are the likely root causes?

Comment: It would seem to happen when Chef can't find an item in a data bag. Perhaps you could debug it with data_bag_items? [1](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Data+Bags) [2](http://rubydoc.info/gems/chef/0.10.4/Chef/Mixin/Language)

Comment: can you paste chef-client -l debug output?

Comment: Really don't have enough here to answer this question.

Comment: You might also consider going to the Chef IRC (http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/IRC),where you can work this question in an interactive fashion). I have found it an invaluable resource.

Answer (score 0):

Some more info would be helpful here. What workflow are you going down when you see this?

I'm going to make an assumption that it's not  a knife call. I attempted to put in some debug around the source of your error in the chef-gem and called data bag list and data bag show. Neither seemed to hit the mixin code.

The following is the source of your error in the chef gem under mixin/language

```
def data_bag(bag)
  DataBag.validate_name!(bag.to_s)
  rbag = DataBag.load(bag)
  rbag.keys
  rescue Exception
    Log.error("Failed to list data bag items in data bag: #{bag.inspect}")
  raise
end
```

Now I'm at a loss as to what is accessing that mixin code because all other references to data_bag() in the gem refer to the code around the data_bag_item object.

Is this custom code you've created? Is there a chance you are referencing the wrong module?

Answer (score 0):

You normally get this error when Chef cannot find the data bag "id"

Say I would like to load the following data_bag

```
data_bags
    apps
        mywebserver.json


apps
    recipes
        default.rb

[mywebserver.json]
{
     "id": "mywebserver"
}

[default.rb]
data_bag_item("apps", "mywebserver")  # The id specified in the json
```

I believe chef does not care for the data_bag_item file name but only cares for the "id" specified in one of the data bag item json files.